# read_html returns NA

Tags: r, rvest, httr

I've been looking for a solution to scrape a site with R for a month without a favorable response.

Here is what I tried on R but the answer remains #NA.  I don't know why.

```
library(rvest)
url<-read_html("https://www.richbourse.com/common/mouvements/technique/SPHC")
col_name<- url%>%
  html_nodes("th")%>%
  html_text()
data <- url%>%
  html_nodes("td") %>%
  html_text()
data
#Na
```

When I tried the following code:

```
url<-"https://www.richbourse.com/common/mouvements/technique/SPHC"
read_html(url1) 
# {html_document} 
# <html lang="fr-FR"> 
# [1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<meta name="csrf-para ... 
# [2] <body>\n\n\n<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KK5FBSF"height ...
```

Thanks for all advices. I try another issues to get the table but it remains some little problems.
Code  Review : Now it remains only two problems:
1- Change date in date format
2- Catch the trading volume column
Still thinking about it

```
library("httr")
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
link <- "https://www.richbourse.com/common/mouvements/technique/SPHC"
#Get link
page <- GET(link)
#Data before decoding
page[["content"]]
```

After decoding and data become as character

```r
page <- content(page,as="text",encoding = 'UTF-8')
page
p=unlist(strsplit(page,split = '\n'))
p=unlist(strsplit(p[[641]],split = ':'))
p[2]
##Keeping for emergency
pp<-p[2]
```

Cleaning data

```
#To be sure that there is no space in the  character
pp1<-gsub(" ", "", pp)
#Remove all second square bracket closer to a comma
pp_split1<-strsplit(pp1, split = "],")
##Transform to data frame
pp_split2<- as.data.frame(pp_split1)
#Use a loop to remove the remaining square brackets in each row
i= 1
for (i in 1 : nrow(pp_split2)){
  pp_split2[i,1]<- gsub("\\[|\\]", "", pp_split2[i,1])
  #pp_split2[i,1]<-gsub("\\[", "", pp_split2[i,1])
}
#Now transform one column to 5 columns
#And change numbers in integer
colnames(pp_split2)<-c("unique")
pp_split2<-separate(pp_split2, col = unique, into =  c("Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close"), sep = ",")
pp_split2$Open<-as.numeric(pp_split2$Open)
pp_split2$High<-as.numeric(pp_split2$High)
pp_split2$Low<-as.numeric(pp_split2$Low)
pp_split2$Close<-as.numeric(pp_split2$Close)

### If we want we can transform it to tibble
pp_split3<- as_tibble(pp_split2)
```

[image][image]
Attached images show How the table looks on the web. Image 1 shows here to click to open data table.
Image 2 present the table. After the scraping i lost the trading volume and all date change to character

Comment: FYI, in the StackOverflow question area, code-blocks are made by starting with three backticks `\`\`\`` ***on their own line***, followed by code (with no other backticks required), and then another three backticks `\`\`\`` ***also on their own line***. There is no need to do it to every line of code (which is quite cumbersome.

Comment: This is a dynamic webpage where the data loads via an XHR request run by the javascript on the page. It may be possible to get the data you want with other web scraping techniques, but not trying to scrape with rvest. Unfortunately, I can't even tell what you are _trying_ to extract here - the page has a plot on it, not a table

Comment: The help page for html_nodes says that function has been replaced by `html_elements`. And the answer is not NA, it's `character(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a node by that name. If you use `html_elements`, which the help page says is the replacement for `html_nodes`, and choose a name that is present in the page, such as "li", you do get results:

```
 url<-read_html("https://www.richbourse.com/common/mouvements/technique/SPHC")
>col_name<- url%>%
     html_elements("li")%>%
     html_text()
 col_name
#------console output-----------
 [1] ""                                                                                                                                                                        
 [2] ""                                                                                                                                                                        
 [3] ""                                                                                                                                                                        
 [4] ""                                                                                                                                                                        
 [5] " Newsletter"                                                                                                                                                             
 [6] " Contact"                                                                                                                                                                
 [7] " Inscription"                                                                                                                                                            
 [8] " Connexion"                                                                                                                                                              
 [9] "Marchés Publications officielles\nActualités\nActions\nIndices\nObligations\nPalmarès hebdomadaires"                                                                     
[10] "Publications officielles"                                                                                                                                                
snipped the remaining 76 items
```

Also works for the name: "options"

```
 col_name<- url%>%
     html_elements("option")%>%
     html_text()
 col_name
 #------------------------
 [1] " -- action --"                               "PALM COTE D'IVOIRE"                         
 [3] "SAPH COTE D'IVOIRE"                          "SICOR COTE D'IVOIRE"                        
 [5] "SOGB COTE D'IVOIRE"                          "SUCRIVOIRE COTE D'IVOIRE"                   
 [7] "SETAO COTE D'IVOIRE"                         "BERNABE COTE D'IVOIRE"                      
 [9] "CFAO MOTORS COTE D'IVOIRE"                   "SERVAIR ABIDJAN COTE D'IVOIRE" 
  #---- snipped remaining 39 items-------
```

Comment: I try another issue. I edit the old request. It is at the top

Comment: I answered your question.